# Is it possible to make an AIR app run on startup?

Tags: air, startup, flash-builder

Is it possible to make my AIR app able to add itself to the list of startup programs? (I'd like to make this work on multiple platforms - namely, Windows, Mac and Linux) How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (NativeApplication.supportsStartAtLogin)
{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true;
}
```

This will start application when user logs in, not OS starts, but it's closest thing you can get.

Comment: I'm using Flash Builder 4 - `NativeApplication.supportsStartAtLogin` doesn't appear in the coding "help". Why?

Comment: How do you check? On my FB 3.2, NativeApplication is recognized without imports when used in MXML. In .as file it should be imported with import flash.desktop.NativeApplication.

Comment: I check by typing. So if I import the right `flash.desktop` package, then `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin = true` works, but the check for support does not.

Answer (score 0):

See:
["Out of browser" web application running at Start-Up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251589/out-of-browser-web-application-running-at-start-up)

The top answer:

The bkMark application from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/samples_javascript.html
shows how to make an AIR app run at start-up.